# NGRX 4 store without a model using any

Tags: angular, redux, ngrx, ngrx-store

I am trying to use ngrx store state without a model like

```
export interface AppStore{
    competitions:any[];
}
```

But when doing it returns undefined i donot k now how to use the action payload on any i am tired searching for it please help

```
this.store.select('competitions').subscribe(data=> console.log(data)).unsubscribe();
```

I always get undefined Please help

**USING NGRX**

Created a STATE in component

```
export interface AppState{
    comp:any;
}

ngOnInit(){
        this.store.dispatch({type:GET_COMP,payload: {}});
}
```

**ACTIONS**

```
export const GET_COMP = 'GET_COMP';
export const SUCCESS = 'SUCCESS';

export class GetAction implements Action {
  readonly type = GET_COMP;

  constructor(public payload: any) {}
}

export class SuccessAction implements Action {
  readonly type = SUCCESS;

  constructor(public payload: any) {}
}

export type Actions =
  | GetAction
  | SuccessAction
;
```

**EFFECTS**

```
@Injectable()
export class MainEffects {

  constructor(private action$: Actions, private service$ :CompetitionService ) { }

  @Effect() load$:Observable<Action> = this.action$
      // Listen for the 'LOGIN' action
      .ofType(GET_COMP)
      .switchMap(action => this.service$.getComp()
        // If successful, dispatch success action with result
        .map(res => ({ type: SUCCESS, payload: res}))
        // If request fails, dispatch failed action
        .catch((err) => Observable.of({ type: 'FAILED' ,payload :err}))  
      );
}
```

**REDUCER**

```
export function MainReducer(state = [],action: GetAction) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case GET_COMP:
            return [action.payload];
        default:
            return state;
  }
}
```

**APP.MODULE**

```
StoreModule.forRoot({MainReducer}),
EffectsModule.forRoot([MainEffects])
```

**Reducer Factory**

```
export const reducers: ActionReducerMap<AppStore> = {
     competitions: MainReducer
};
```

Comment: Did you already read the migration guide in @ngrx/platform?

Comment: yes @Jota.Toledo https://github.com/ngrx/platform/blob/master/MIGRATION.md I just cant grasp it . Do we even need to change this code i am confused \

Comment: How about you try to convert it in a repo or plunker and tell us where you get stuck?